# Access Denied when creating file in Visual F#

Tags: f#, access-denied, writer

The following code runs without a hitch: [image]

On the other hand, I get an access-denied error with this:[image]

The destination is in my personal folder and I have full control. The directory is not read-only. Anyway, in either of those cases, the first code sample should not run either! I appreciate the help ...

Comment: Please always post your code as text with appropriate indentation; the screenshots make it more difficult than it needs to be. Other than that, the first path has slashes, the second one has backslashes, which may lead to some characters being inadvertently escaped; have you tried putting an @ before the path string to prevent that?

Comment: Thanx, I though a jpg would be better since when I click it, it enlarges with all indentations and highlighting. In any case, adding the @ does not help. Changing the slashes to backslashes do not help either.

Comment: Post the text anyway because it's impossible to read or *execute* the code shown in a jpg. We'll format it

Comment: As for the second snippet as others mentioned, the path doesn't point to a file, it points to a folder. You can't write over a folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second sample, you have two problems:

1. There are back slashes instead of forward slashes, so some of them may get interpreted as escape sequences.
2. You completely ignore the first parameter of `write` and specify what I assume is a folder as destination. You can't open a file stream on a folder, no wonder you get access denied.

This should work:

```
let write filename (ms:MemoryStream) =
  let path = System.IO.Path.Combine( "C:/Users/<whatever>/signal_processor", filename )
  use fs = new FileStream( path, FileMode.Create )
  ms.WriteTo(fs)
```